# Infopath: Copy calculated value to list field

Tags: infopath, calculated-column

I'm using InfoPath and SP 2010.
I'm using calculated fields which works well, but I wonder if there is a way to copy calculated field value to standard list field when form is submitted ?

Comment: Hi Maciej, are the calculated fields in the sharepoint list or in the Infopath form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Calculated value** in Infopath is control, OOTB (out of the box), i.e. just visual container. Controls can be  bound or not to data fields (and vice versa, it is possible to have data fields without there visual rendering). OOTB, when you drag'n'drop **Calculated value** control from ribbon in Infopath Designer (**IPD**), it <s>is not bound to</s>  doesn't create a data source/field bound to control.

- **Update**: In contrast, most (if not all) other controls when drag'n'dropped from ribbon of IPD are simultaneously creating bound to them data field.

As such, it is impossible to copy (or submit) controls to Sharepoint, only data in data fields. One creates data fields without controls in **Fields pane** (former Data Source pane in IP 2007) and then can bind or not them to controls.
OOTB (**update:** see Update3 below), there are no data field of type "calculated value" in Infopath though you can create a data field, then use rules or default value to calculate there whatever value you want.

It is also not clear what you mean under "standard list field"

- **Update**:
  or where your calculated values work well - in Infopath form or in Sharepoint.
  Further on, I assumed that in Infopath form.
  It is the easiest way to put fields from Infopath form into Sharepoint.
  Other way around, putting them first in Sharepoint, in most cases are redundant to the steps to be made in Infoapth Designer and frequently leading to type mismatches between Sharepoint and Infopath.

If you meant under it a sharepoint list then Infopath **Sharepoint List Form** data fields are directly (and rigidly) linked to its sharepoint list fields.
If you meant under it a sharepoint library then you should promote a data field during publishing your Infopath template in order to have it copied to a  field in sharepoint library.

[image]

**Update2**:
I've just checked that if to create a **calculated column** in a sharepoint list first, then creating its **Sharepoint List Form** by pressing **Customize Form** button (in Sharepoint Designer or in a browser), the corresponding to it field is created in Infopath form template as a data field without any corresponding control.  So, it requires creating a corresponding control (by drag'n'dropping from or right-clicking and choosing options in **Fields pane**) to be visible to users.

Update3:
This is funny. Unmodifiable CalculatedType appeared for a data field through creating a calculated column in sharepoint list (from sharepoint side),  but it is impossible to attribute such type directly from Infopath.

[image]

**Update4** (in response to comments): 
I wanted (but didn't) to reply to your first comment that you probably misunderstood something in my answer. It is better if a person comes to conclusions having poked himself. Then, I had a vague vanity that your happiness will somehow pass through unbroken.

First, do not use calculated value control for your purposes - its data source is **expression but not data field**. It is data fields that are linked to sharepoint list and possible to submit to it.
In Infopath 2007, 2010's calculated value control  had more fortunate and less misleading name - **Expression Box**.

Second, if you decided to use Infopath, then try hard to use its OOTB features (behavior) without overriding them, they will be pain in the ass if you override them.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt realize I can bind calculated field to existing list field!

Comment: RE: "drag'n'dropped from ribbon of IPD are simultaneously creating bound to them data field" - this is actually what I expected here - that's why I even didnt try to bind it 'manually' :)

Comment: Oh seems it was too early happines... I thought I can setup math rule in calc value control (in IP) than bind such to existing field from SP list (eg TOTAL_PRICE) and than calculate value control will submit data back to SP. Tunred out that when I bind it my rule is beeing replaced by bound field reference..... :(

Comment: +1, see my Update4. I did not reply to your 1st comment NOT because I did not read it or did not care. I just felt a sorrow that I couldn't explain that calculated value control in Infopath 2010 is former Expression Box control in 2007 with less misleading notation. And one has either expression (based on data values in "other" data fields) or data field as data source, not both

Comment: [Saga continued](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64808/do-calculated-columns-work-on-an-infopath-form-based-list/64811#64811) but my point is that there is no necessity to create sharepoint calcilated columns. This all being done more easily directly in Infopath designer without meddling in the "help" intermediary engagement from the sharepoint side